# The network list doesn't show all the available WiFi networks (22.04, 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, hot-spot, 22.04

I just upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 to  22.04.
The problem is that my personal hotspot doesn't show up in the networks list.
Well, the network does show sometimes. But not all the time.
I had the same issue with ubuntu 20.04 too.

My network adapter: BCM43142

Please do suggest a fix.
And please feel free to ask for other necessary information too.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Why do you think this is an issue with Ubuntu?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. Cause the network does show in another machine that runs windows. But I don't know if the issue is with my hardware.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try "sudo nmcli device wifi rescan"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manually setting the wifi channel on the router. Since I changed it 5 days ago I've had no more problems detecting my wifi.

The steps I did are:

1. `sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep -i channel:`
2. Note any listed channel that is not used by many networks.
3. Login to the router and set the wifi channel manually to the noted channel.